# Allow DataGridView to grow and shrink height based on row data

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a datagridview that I would like to automatically grow and shrink horizontally based on the data inside, rather than having the datagrid maintain its static height and show a scroll bar.

The form has a TableLayoutPanel with one column and three rows; the column and rows are set to autosize. The DataGridView is in the second row (as seen in the picture) and has the following relevant properties:

- Anchor: Top Left
- AutoSizeColumnsMode: DisplayedCells
- AutoSizeRowsMode: None
- Dock: Fill

Whenever the rows surpass the viewable area, a scroll bar appears, but I'd like the datagridview to grow with the rows. How can I accomplish this?

*Note: We have logic in place to ensure that the form never grows past the users monitor size.*

[image: Dialog window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue with the following method that I pass my datagrid as an argument to (there is no non-code solution to handle this scenario).

```
Public Sub AdjustHeightOfGridBasedOnRows(ByVal dataGrid As DataGridView)
    Dim totalRowHeight As Integer = dataGrid.ColumnHeadersHeight

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dataGrid.Rows
        totalRowHeight += row.Height
    Next

    dataGrid.Height = totalRowHeight
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to subscribe to the RowsAdded and RowsRemoved event of the DataGridView. So whenever the amount of rows change, the size adjusts accordingly.

```vb
''' <summary>
''' Adujsts the height of a DataGridView when rows are added or removed.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="sender">This will be the DataGridView which will be modified</param>
''' <param name="e">The event args of from the addition or removal of a row</param>
''' <remarks>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24186771/allow-datagridview-to-grow-and-shrink-height-based-on-row-data</remarks>
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowsAdded(sender As DataGridView, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowsAdded, DataGridView1.RowsRemoved
    If sender.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim newHeight As Integer = 0
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In sender.Rows
            newHeight += row.Height
        Next

        ' Need to have this size doubled to give the buffer room for horizontal scroll bar.
        ' without it, if the horizontal scroll bar is displayed, then it will put in the 
        ' vertical scroll bar for the last row. If the column headers are hidden, then 
        ' add the height of the first row.
        If sender.ColumnHeadersVisible Then
            newHeight += sender.ColumnHeadersHeight * 2
        Else
            newHeight += sender.Rows(0).Height
        End If
        sender.Height = newHeight
    End If
End Sub
```